# Update Copied Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I created query that copies data from an ODBC table and inserts it into an local table in Accesss. How can I update my locally copied table when the OBDC is updated or changed?

Answer (score 0):

Don't import the table. Link it and use the linked table, not a local table.